# Access xml file on protected Sharepoint Website in Android Code

Tags: android, sharepoint

I am trying to access an XML file on a username and password protected Sharpoint website from an Android app.  Using:

URL url = new URL("http://username:password@thewebsite.com/file/test.xml);

URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

results in a file not found exception.  If I turn the username/password requirement off on the website it works, but it does not find the file when I change it to require username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading a file like this is not going to work, because you aren't authenticated to SharePoint (the error it throws is not actually an FileNotFoundException but most likely an AccessDenied Exception - you will have to look up the SharePoint ULS Log in the 14/LOGS folder).

I'm not a android dev (neither java) but i guess the best way to do this is to use the SharePoint web services, especially the [Copy Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You'll have to generate a client proxy class from the web service's .wsdl file, and then you can call it via code.

Someone [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-through-soap-web-servic) tried to achieve something similar (only uploading instead of downloading) so this should give you a good head-start with your solution. Also [here](http://tipsforsharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/02/download-file-using-sharepoint-copy-web.html) is a piece of code which you might need - it's in C# but you should be able to translate it to Java.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the info, I hadn't considered the NTLM security.  Your suggestions lead me to this:  http://maxters.net/2011/08/android-ntlm-authenication-made-easy/ which ended up solving my problem, thanks!